# Apache: incap_ses_* cookie is Secure but not HttpOnly, whereas visid_incap_* have both flags

Tags: wordpress, apache, apache2, session-cookies, apache-modules

I have an Apache server that hosts a Wordpress webpage. I modified my `mod_headers` to set the `Secure` and `HttpOnly` flag to all the cookies.
My configuration is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
</IfModule>
```

For some reason the `incap_ses` cookie only appears with the Secure flag, and the `visid_incap` have both `Secure` and `HttpOnly` flags.

Is there a reason why that specific cookie (`incap_ses`) doesn't appear with the `HttpOnly` flag too?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to fix this.
Try `always` in front of `edit` i.e. `always edit`
 Also make sure that you list a line uses `always` before any lines that has just use `edit`
`Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1;HttpOnly;Secure"`

But best practice would be to handle this in a `PHP` file. Then add something like this to the `.htaccess`.

```
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
# END WordPress
# BEGIN HttpHeaders
php_flag session.cookie_httponly on
php_flag session.cookie_secure on
# END HttpHeadersCookie
```